# Retrieve binary from STM32W108 using JTAG

Tags: binary, jtag

I want to retrieve the binary file that has been loaded on a STM32W108 using JTAG. Has anyone done this before? If yes, can you post the instruction or and link to the instructions

Much appreciate.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you specify what IDE you're using, then I might be able to give you more accurate instructions.

**Here is the general method:**

1. Open the linker-command file of your project and check the address space of the executable. You can also look for it in the map file, but you'll need to build the project first. Please note that the code-section and the data-section possibly reside in two separate memory regions.
2. Load the executable to RAM, or burn it to EPROM (whichever way you usually do it).
3. Search for the Memory-Save option, typically in either the View menu or the Debug menu.
4. Enter the memory address and size you found earlier, and click OK.